# How to get the object key and value into an array in JS?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object

```
var students = { 0: "Ann_L", 1: "Bob_P", 2: "Cat_C" }
```

How can I get an array from the object with its key and value?

```
var array = [ 
    { "Id": 0, "Value": "Ann_L", "Name": "Ann L" },
    { "Id": 1, "Value": "Bob_P", "Name": "Bob P" },
    { "Id": 2, "Value": "Cat_C", "Name": "Cat C" }
]
```

I have the values of the object but not the keys for "Id"

```
var array = Object.entries(students).map(([_, student ]) => 
    ({
        Name: student.replace(/_/g, " "), 
        Id: ?,
        Value: student 
    })
```

Comment: `_` contains your key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is the first element in the entries array

```
var array = Object.entries(students).map(([key, student ]) => 
({
    Name: student.replace(/_/g, " "), 
    Id: key,
    Value: student 
})
```

Comment: Minor note: `key` will be a string, if `Id` is supposed to be a number, you probably want `Id: +key`.

Answer (score 2):

**Object.entries** return `[key, value]` so in your code `_` is `key`

You can use [**Object.entries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [**replace**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
var students = { 0: "Ann_L", 1: "Bob_P", 2: "Cat_C" }

let op = Object.entries(students).map(([Id,value]) => {
  return {
    Id,
    value,
    name: value.replace(/_/g, ' ')
  }
})

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could assign the object to an array and map the objects.

```js
var students = { 0: "Ann_L", 1: "Bob_P", 2: "Cat_C" },
    array = Object
        .assign([], students)
        .map((Value, Id) => ({ Id, Value, Name: Value.replace(/_/g, ' ') }));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `Object.assign([], students)` is clever.

Comment: While the `Object.assign` call **is** clever, it's perhaps a bit too clever, as it will only work properly if the keys are `0`, `1`, `2`, etc., albeit in any order.  `Object.entries(students).map(...)` is clearer and less fragile.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution: you can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and iterate through the `students` object using the keys.

```js
const students = { 0: "Ann_L", 1: "Bob_P", 2: "Cat_C" }

const res = Object.keys(students).map((element, index) => {
  return {
    Id: element,
    Value: students[index],
    Name: students[index].replace(/_/g, " "),  
  }
})

console.log(res)
```